# Creating objects using a 3 deep serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm encountering a problem with django rest framework, where I have the following serializer setup:

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Package


class CommandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Command


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)

class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    packages = PackageSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    commands = CommandSerializer(many=True, required=False)

class SimulationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nodes = NodeSerializer(many=True)
```

The problem I'm encountering is that if I post the JSON below to the appropriate API, I get the response "expected a dictionary, but got unicode.".

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "os": "Ubuntu",
      "cpu_count": 1,
      "memory_amount": 256,
      "name": "Node1",
      "packages": [
        {
          "name": "npm"
        },
        {
          "name": "bower"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've written tests for this functionality in python using the rest-framework API, which pass, but for some reason the array of package objects is being converted as a string, not as an array of objects.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The JSON in your post looks fine, but maybe the actuall data you're trying to post is enclosed within quotation marks: ``u"{"nodes" ...}"``. Check it in the interactive python mode using ``type()``.

Comment: The JSON in the post is the output of JSON.stringify(), as I'm posting the data from an angular frontend to the DRF API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out I was just being an idiot, that output was from a variable I was outputting to console, meanwhile I was posting different data.